# Cassandra Datastax Driver set paging state on Accessor

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I'm using Datastax's lovely java driver for cassandra.  I was trying to encapsulate all of my query strings into the built in accessors for mapping, but I require the ability to set the paging state for a query.

I see that this is possible with a normal Statement (SimpleStatement), but I haven't found the corresponding functionality for an Accessor.  Does it exist, or do I have skip using Accessors for this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this would be really nice to have.

One way to work with this for now would be to have your accessor return a Statement, i.e.:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ks.tbl WHERE id = ?")
Statement getAllById(@Param("id") UUID userId);
```

And then from there you call `setPagingState` on the `Statement` returned and execute it.

I agree that this isn't as nice as providing the paging state as a parameter to the Accessor, so I went ahead and opened up [JAVA-1103](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1103).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [Achilles](https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles/wiki/):

```
manager
   .select()
    .allColumns_FromBaseTable()
    .where()
    .partitionKey_Eq(...)
    ...
    .withPagingState(PagingState.fromString(...))
    .getList();
```