# How to pass Paging state in Cassandra accessor interface using cassandra java driver (version 3.6)?

Tags: java, cassandra

We have a requirement to allow pagination in cassandra accessor results.
We have @Accessor annotated interface with @Query annotated method signatures that returns Result.
There is an option to pass page size for the query in @QueryParameters annotation but there is no way to pass page state for fetching next set of records if the query results are paginated. How do I achieve this without changing the return types of my accessor interface?

I have tried the solution mentioned in this:

[Cassandra Datastax Driver set paging state on Accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679055/cassandra-datastax-driver-set-paging-state-on-accessor)

But this would require me to change my accessor methods to return Statement object instead of Result, and that is not acceptable.

Is there a better approach for this?

Please note that we are not using Spring framework (Unfortunately!)

Answer (score 0):

The use of the accessor combined with `setPagingState` is the most stable solution that will allow you to have the same behaviour and performance of the query, regardless the size of the table, as it will handle with a fixed amount of records at a time.