# how to pass paging state to Cassandra accessor interface in java 8

Tags: java-8, cassandra

I just started on Cassandra and i'm trying to paginate the result.
I hope to user only `Assessor` ,but can't seem to find a way to pass `pagingState` to the `Accessor` query.

```
@Accessor
public interface SomeAccessor {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM some_data where some_id = :?") //pass pagingSate here
    public Result getSomeValues(String id);}
```

Is there any way to pass paging state to Cassandra `Accessor` interface??

I can't seem to find any answer in the docs.

I have gone through few answer here

[answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679055/cassandra-datastax-driver-set-paging-state-on-accessor)

[answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56555650/how-to-pass-paging-state-in-cassandra-accessor-interface-using-cassandra-java-dr)

But none of them clearly solves my issue .

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, describe your question better and improve formatting.

Comment: done few edits ,please let me know what else is needed